# reduce the steps it takes to format string

Tags: java, android, string, formatting

working on finishing up an android application, though trying to tidy up a bit. I have this code where I have text view and an integer and im adding the int at the end by formatting, and then using `.setText(temp)` to display it to the screen for that text view. here is the code

```
    public void pink_pressed(View view) {
    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    incorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    String temp;
    if (count != 0 && !(count > NUMBER_ROUNDS)) {
        if (color == pink) {
            cor++;
            temp = String.format("correct    : %d", cor);
            correct.setText(temp);
        } else {
            inc++;
            temp = String.format("incorrect : %d", inc);
            incorrect.setText(temp);
        }
        start_pressed(view);
    }
}
```

specifically im wanting to reduce these two lines to one.

```
            temp = String.format("correct    : %d", cor);
            correct.setText(temp);
```

I tried things like:

```
correct.setText(R.@string.num_cor + cur);
```

or

```
correct.setText(R.@string.num_cor +Integer.toString(cur));
```

where `num_cor` is just the same string as "correct   : "

and ideas of a possible fix to this problem?

Comment: You can use `getString(resId)` to get the string from string resources. But you still need to use `String.format()` to format it. Edit: On the other hand, you can just put `String.format()` inside `TextView.setText()`.

Comment: could you give me the line of code. what i tried broke the app `correct.setText(String.format(R.string.num_cor + getString(cor)));`

Comment: lol. you can replace the 3 lines inside `if(color==pink)` by `correct.setText(String.format("correct    : %d", ++cor));`

Comment: use 'temp = "correct : " + cor;' and 'temp = "incorrect : " + inc;'

Comment: @SherifelKhatib if i did that how would i know if i need to go to the bottom then (the else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
```

Make sure you have the following in your strings:

```
<string name="num_cor">correct : %d</string>
```

Comment: it doesnt break the app, though it is not displaying the integer where i need it to be

Comment: @erp post the XML where you define the string for `num_cor`.

Comment: @erp then the string is not the same. Your other string was `correct    : %d`

Answer (score 0):

public final String getString (int resId, Object... formatArgs)

correct.setText(context.getString(resID, correctNum));

Comment: what are you referring to by context? sorry im still a beginner

Comment: @erp if you are in Activity, then the Activity itself is an Context. If you are in Widget like TextView, use textView.getContext().

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a string resource you need to use `R.string.string_name` rather than `R.@string.string_name` as you've used.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `R.string.string_name` is not the string itself, it's an integer reference to the string in the resource XML files, if you want the string itself you need to use `getString(..)`.

Putting this all together, if you have the following in your strings.xml:

```
<string name="num_cor">correct : %d</string>
```

Then the following should do the job:

```
correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor, cor));
```

Alternatively if you had this in your strings.xml:

```
<string name="num_cor">correct : </string>
```

You could use:

```
correct.setText(getString(R.string.num_cor) + cur);
```